# Store javascript object having public methods in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

I need to store a javascript variable(object) in local storage and retrieve it back.

When i type this variable on console - below is how it looks to be.

```
>> getTopWindow().mylist


Object {indexOf: function, setPosition: function, getPosition: function, 
length: function, getCurrentBreadCrumbTrail: function…}
clear: function ()
currentPosition: function ()
getCurrentBC: function ()
getCurrentBreadCrumbTrail: function ()
getPosition: function ()
indexOf: function (id)
setPosition: function (position)
__proto__:Object
```

How can i store this in local storage and retrieve this object back. I'm not finding a way to do so. Please advice

Comment: sort of not possible because toJSON does not support it. Why do you need to store methods? It seems like a bad design.

Comment: @epascarello: It's *possible*, it's just (as you say) bad design. Mohan - This sounds like an X/Y problem. Why do you think you need to store the object, complete with its functions? The normal thing would be to store only state data, and then create a new object (with its functions) and assign the state data to it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The sort of not possible is because yes you can store methods, but it ain't going to maintain variable states.

Comment: @epascarello: Yeah, if there's data in closures.

Comment: Not only the methods, the variable is an object array - and each element has private data stored and can be retrieved using this public methods. Somehow i need to store this data completely and reassign after a specific operation(where this variable would get cleared)

This would store all user visited nodes - so i need to store this and retrieve back.

Comment: You mean it's not possible to store the data? Any other alternative you suggest?